# Delete hanging edge orientdb

Tags: orientdb, orientdb-2.1

Is there a way to delete all hanging reference to edges I have unsafely deleted in orientdb ?

I typed `drop class MyEdge unsafe` in orientdb, but reference to this edge in outs of other vertices weren't deleted.

Any idea what is the right command I should have used to delete an edge and its references ?

I'm using orientdb 2.1.19

Thank you

Comment: any error message?

Comment: Have you tried `delete MyEdge` ?

Comment: `delete` was to delete a single edge, I want to delete a whole class. I don't have the error right now sorry, but it was telling me that the edge was not found.

Comment: How about `TRUNCATE CLASS MyEdge UNSAFE`?

Comment: Same issue with truncate - pointers to MyEdge are not deleted

Comment: Works with `delete vertex MyEdge` to delete all edges from class. Then use `drop class myEdge`

Answer (score 1):

Starting from OrientDB 2.2.x the command `CHECK DATABASE` has been introduced, in case the database contains graphs, their consistency is checked. To repair a database, use the `REPAIR DATABASE` command.

For more information about `CHECK DATABASE`: https://orientdb.com/docs/last/Console-Command-Check-Database.html

For more information about `REPAIR DATABASE`: https://orientdb.com/docs/last/Console-Command-Repair-Database.html

Hope it helps

Regards